# Cassandra Batch

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cassandra, insert

I has just started newly with Cassandra, and I had one common question that
"Suppose I need to insert nearly about 2000+ records, most of people do say that don't use batch here, but on the other side also heard that **"The closest feature to a stored procedure will be a batch as it will allow you to "bundle" different DML statements associated to an insert, update or delete."**

So can anyone suggest what is the best way where I can create once, store and call for several times whenever it is required which can support faster execution as SP's in SQL

Comment: The batch-file tag is about how to copy files on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batches in Cassandra have very specific usage:

- to apply multiple changes at one, often to multiple tables, to provide consistency in the update of the data, guaranteeing that they all will be applied, or all will fail.   This often called "logged batch" - in this case, Cassandra is doing a copy of batch on the multiple servers before applying changes, and delete after successful apply of batch operations.  As result, such batches are much slower than usual operations.
- to apply multiple operations inside the single partition - often it's called "unlogged batch" - in this case, all operations are considered as one mutation, and as result this is very fast, compared to multiple individual operations.

So batches could be used for multiple inserts/updates/deletes only inside single partition (otherwise you'll get worse performance compared to the individual statements), or when you need consistency of data between several tables.  The fastest way to insert a lot of data is to issue multiple async operations.  Also, if you want to load data from files, then maybe it's better to look to the tools like [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) that are heavily optimized for high performance load & unload of the data.

In more details about good & bad use of batches you can read in [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html), and DSE Architecture guide.

P.S. Technically speaking, Cassandra does classify batches either as multipatitioned - in this case they are always logged, or single partition - they aren't logged.